# Configurable products for different product sizes and price

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I am trying to make a store for car care chemicals in Magento for online buyers and company distributors.

Each chemical has a size option - 0.5 liters, 5 liters, 207 liters

And the above options have price difference depending upon the customer is a normal buyer or a distributor.

I have made a configurable product, but the price in the 
"Super product attributes configuration" overrides the Group pricing in the simple products.

Can somebody please suggest the right way?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Then it doesn't belong on SO. This is a programming-related Q&A site. Try posting on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a attribute "size" as dropdown with all possible sizes.

When you add the product you have to choose one of them.

Comment: Already done that. I have 3 simple products made with the size attribute. The problem is the price of 5 liter option is not showing. http://119.81.28.106/~kkeautocare/index.php/soaps-and-shampoos/kke-car-wash-shampoo.html

Answer (score 0):

Magento will not take into the account the  simple products' price of a configurable one. Simple products' prices are ignored. if you want to sell a simple product X having price $120 and a simple product B ($130) then set configurable product's price to $120 and add products you want to associate with this configurable product. After adding them click on 'Associated Products' tab which opens a block named Super product attributes configuration, which contains options and price differences and set the prices accordingly as described in attached image.

Moreover There's an extension that allows you to use simple product prices instead of price differences Since it's free extension. The extension is "Simple Configurable Products(SCP)".

[image]